# How can I put a minitoc before a chapter, on the facing page?

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, minitoc

I'm writing a large book, using minitoc to put a small table of contents at the start of each chapter.  But it looks terrible.

I would like instead to put the minitoc on the facing page *before* the first page of the chapter.  For example, if Chapter 9 starts on page 503, then I would like the minitoc for Chapter 9 to appear on page 502.

I know how to clear to an even page.  The question is what do I use instead of `\minitoc` to get the minitoc for the *next* chapter rather than the current one?

---

Related question: [How to put a figure on the facing page of a chapter page with correct numbering?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137563/how-to-put-a-figure-on-the-facing-page-of-a-chapter-page-with-correct-numbering)

Comment: I'm tempted to try something vicious like increment the `chapter` counter, `\minitoc`, decrement the `chapter` counter.  But maybe there is a right way to do it?

Comment: the `memoir` class has an `openleft` option.  maybe that could be useful.

Comment: when I saw the question title my first thought was to do exactly what you suggest in the comment, so I'd make that an answer:-)

Comment: @NormanRamsey: I suggest to use jfbu's solution -- it works out of the box!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [etoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc) for this, via its label/ref mechanism for tocs.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\cleartoevenpage {%
   \clearpage 
   \if@twoside \ifodd \c@page \hbox {}\newpage 
        \if@twocolumn \hbox {}\newpage \fi 
   \fi \fi }
\makeatother


\begin{document}


\tableofcontents


% switch to article like style for table of contents
% (else they will start like chapters on odd numbered pages)
% would need adjustment in two-column mode

\etocarticlestyle
\renewcommand*\etocbeforetitlehook {\cleartoevenpage}


\tableofcontents\ref{toc:first}

\chapter{First}
\invisiblelocaltableofcontents\label{toc:first}

\section{Foo}
\blindtext[2]

\subsection{FooFoo}
\blindtext[5]
\subsubsection{FooFooFoo}
\blindtext[5]

\section{Foo2}
\blindtext[3]

\subsection{FooFoo2}
\blindtext[7]
\subsubsection{FooFooFoo2}
\blindtext[7]


\tableofcontents\ref{toc:bar}
\chapter{Bar}
\invisiblelocaltableofcontents\label{toc:bar}

\section{Bar}
\blindtext[2]

\subsection{BarBar}
\blindtext[5]
\subsubsection{BarBarBar}
\blindtext[5]


\tableofcontents\ref{toc:ear}
\chapter{Ear}
\invisiblelocaltableofcontents\label{toc:ear}

\section{Ear}
\blindtext[2]

\subsection{EarEar}
\blindtext[5]
\subsubsection{EarEarEar}
\blindtext[5]

\section{Ear2}
\blindtext[3]

\subsection{EarEar2}
\blindtext[7]
\subsubsection{EarEarEar2}
\blindtext[7]


\tableofcontents\ref{toc:fur}
\chapter{Fur}
\invisiblelocaltableofcontents\label{toc:fur}

\section{Fur}
\blindtext[2]

\subsection{FurFur}
\blindtext[5]
\subsubsection{FurFurFur}
\blindtext[5]


\end{document}
```

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks really interesting.  I think I may be able to do something very powerful with this.

Answer (score 6):

Well, this is a somewhat hidden feature, but `minitoc` provides for the `\adjustmtc` command, that is meant for starred chapters etc., i.e. for the case that the mtc counter is off by one.

This command can be 'misused' to provide the minitoc for the following chapter.

The `\adjustmtc[n]` command is documented on page 34 of the current manual of `minitoc`. The optional argument holds the number of `minitocs` to be incremented (default `n=1`)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\setcounter{minitocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\dominitoc

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\markboth{}{}
\clearpage
\adjustmtc
\minitoc
\chapter{First}

\section{Foo}
\blindtext[2]

\subsection{FooFoo}
\blindtext[5]
\subsubsection{FooFooFoo}
\blindtext[5]
\chapter{Foobar}
\end{document}
```

Please note: The `\setcounter...` statements are just for filling up the `minitoc` etc. with a amount of entries -- they are not important for the functionality.

[image]

**Update** (with some the `\cleartoevenpage` code from `jfbu's answer!)

This works now automatically, i.e. `\chapter` adds the `minitoc` on the even page before.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{minitoc}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\setcounter{minitocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\makeatletter
\let\latex@chapter\chapter

\newcommand*\cleartoevenpage {%
   \clearpage 
   \if@twoside \ifodd \c@page \hbox {}\newpage 
   \if@twocolumn \hbox {}\newpage \fi 
   \fi \fi 
 }

% Automatic addition of minitoc
\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{som}{%
  \def\@@chaptertitlefortoc{#3}%
  \IfValueTF{#2}{%
    \def\@@chaptertitlefortoc{#2}%
  }%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \latex@chapter*{#3}
  }{%
    \cleartoevenpage
    \markboth{}{}%
    \ifnum\value{chapter} = 0
    \adjustmtc
    \fi
    \minitoc
    \latex@chapter[\@@chaptertitlefortoc]{#3}
  }
}



\makeatother

\dominitoc

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}

\section{Foo}
\blindtext[2]

\subsection{FooFoo}
\blindtext[5]
\subsubsection{FooFooFoo}
\blindtext[5]

\chapter{Foobar}
\blindtext[5]
\section{Foo}
\blindtext[5]


\chapter{Foobar other}
\blindtext[5]
\section{Other Foo}
\blindtext[5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: how does it work with more than one chapter ? I tried but did not succeed.

Comment: @jfbu: `\decrementptc` before the next chapter occurs

Comment: doesn't work for me. Can you complete your answer with how it works for you ?

Comment: @jfbu: Actually your `\cleartoevenpage` is quite important to make my solution work, in my point of view. I suggest to use your solution! (I hope you don't mind using `\cleartoevenpage`)

Comment: ok, it works. Your solution is the good one for `minitoc` users. `\cleartoevenpage` is simply `\cleardoublepage` with `odd<->even`. Thus, yes, I guess you may use it. Will consult with my legal advisor though ;-)

Comment: @jfbu: `minitoc` is nice, `etoc` is nice too, but your package is more up-to-date and has the better documentation of course.

Comment: @jfbu: Page shipping out features is not my strongest topic -- the `\cleartoevenpage` macro is quite nice

Comment: too much compliments, I have no other choice but upvoting your answer !

Comment: @jfbu: I've upvoted your solution long ago :-P (thanks!)

Comment: of course, I knew. And guilt proved too much. I couldn't resist during the ad break during my tv movie.