# Minitoc of wrong chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

I'm writing my Thesis and I want the general table of contents at the beginning of the document and the toc for every chapter at beginning of every chapter. For doing so I use the `minitoc` package.

If I put the `\tableofcontents` command at the end of the document all goes right. If instead I put it at the begin of the document the minitoc of first Chapter is not printed and the next ones are shifted. The second chapter has the minitoc of the first one, the third of the second and so on so forth.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\dominitoc

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter{first}
\minitoc
\section{first first}
\section{first second}

\chapter{second}
\minitoc
\section{second first}
\section{second second}

\chapter{third}
\minitoc
\section{third first}
\section{third second}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`memoir` does some redefinitions of ToC features and apparently `minitoc` is confused by this.

However, there is a solution for this: `minitoc` provides the `\adjustmtc[...]` command, the optional argument is meant for adjusting the number of the minitoc, defaulting to one.

Saying `\adjustmtc` before the first `\minitoc` appears cures the problem.

I found this nice command hidden in the `minitoc` documentation when I tried to find a solution for this question: [How can I put a minitoc before a chapter, on the facing page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291533/how-can-i-put-a-minitoc-before-a-chapter-on-the-facing-page/291540#291540).

Please note that `minitoc` is a package that is basically unmaintained since its author, J.P. Drucbert, died in 2009.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\dominitoc

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\adjustmtc
\listoffigures
\adjustmtc
\chapter{first}

\minitoc
\section{first first}
\section{first second}

\chapter{second}
\minitoc
\section{second first}
\section{second second}

\chapter{third}
\minitoc
\section{third first}
\section{third second}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! this works until there is no `\listoffigures` command after `\tableofcontents`. Do you know why?

Comment: @Red: I'll try to figure out

Comment: Don't worry, I just got the solution. It is sufficient to add another `\adjustmtc` after `\listoffigures`

Comment: @Red: Yes, found it too :-) But apparently, `memoir` and `minitoc` are not the best combination

Comment: Yes, I figured it out.. but unfortunately I'm too close to the deadline for changing this evil combination :-)

Comment: @Red: Good luck and go ahead!

Comment: This does not work for me. Perhaps it is because I am importing separate files?

Comment: The `etoc` package is a very good alternative (to `minitoc`).

Comment: memoir and minitoc are the best cominbation :) when it comes to DESIGN :P

Comment: For other people who might have similar problems: in my case, I had to add three consecutive `\adjustmtc`s before my first chapter. I noted that I can actually calculate the amount of `\adjustmt`s required from the shift in the chapter TOCs: without any `\adjustmtc`, chapter and TOC were misaligned by three numbers; each `\adjustmtc` shifted the alignment by one.