# TeXStudio does not recognize the \dominitoc \minitoc commands

Tags: minitoc

I am having a weird problem when trying to produce a mini-toc in each of my chapters in a book I am doing.

I have full TeXLive distribution, and I run Linux. I used the terminal and ran the `kpsewhich minitoc.sty` to confirm it does have the minitoc package installed.

I can add `\usepackage{minitoc}` just fine, but when I try to add `\dominitoc`
before my `\tableofcontents` command as you're supposed to, it shows up red and TeXStudio does not recognize it. Same happens when you try and add `\minitoc` after `\chapter{}`.

I have separate .tex files for each chapter and I am using `\include` (if that is relevant).

Has anyone experienced this on TeXStudio (5.9.5) on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) yet?

These are the other packages I'm using:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
```

Are some of them incompatible with minitoc perhaps?

It is doing something similar when I try to use the titletoc package instead. You can add the package just fine, but when you try to use the associated commands, it is unrecognized.

Edit: upon compiling, it does not produce the mini-toc. It does create auxiliary files though.

Comment: That TeXstudio highlights something red does *not* necessarily mean that it won't work. It could just mean that TeXstudio doesn't load or doesn't have a `.cwl` file (auto completion file) for the package in question. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47493. If the document compiles without error you can just ignore it.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Unfortunately in my case though, it is not producing the minitoc at all. Thanks, I have edited my question to include this.

Comment: If I take your preamble, add the `minitoc` package at the end, and then `\begin{document} \dominitoc \tableofcontents \chapter{f} \minitoc \section{b} \section{c} \end{document}` I do get a minitoc. Does that work for you? Do you compile twice?

Comment: @Torbjørn T, yes tried that quickly, but didn't change anything. I think I have the answer perhaps, well, sort of. I have posted it.

Answer (score 0):

I have come to the conclusion that the fact TeXStudio doesn't recognize the command is not the issue here (as @Torbjørn T suggested), it compiles without any errors. I think the issue is it is assigning the wrong minitoc to the wrong chapters.

After looking through the auxiliary files, I noticed the following files:

- main.mtc
- main.mtc0
- main.mtc1
- main.mtc2
- main.mtc3
- main.mtc4
- main.mtc5

Now, when I open these files, I find main.mtc, main.mtc0, main.mtc1, main.mtc2 and main.mtc5 are empty. But, main.mtc3 and main.mtc4 have the sections of chapter 1 and chapter 2 in my book listed, respectively.

So, immediately I recalled someone who mentioned that they were getting the wrong minitoc for the wrong chapter: [Minitoc of wrong chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291743/minitoc-of-wrong-chapter).

And the lightbulb went off. So I used the `\adjustmtc` command as was suggested in this case and I sort of managed to get a minitoc to show up for one of my chapters, but it's the wrong one for the chapter.

My structure is like this, I have:

- Front matter chapter (unnumbered)
- Front matter chapter (unnumbered)
- Table of Contents
- Chapter 1
- Chapter 2
- Back matter chapter (unnumbered)

I only have two main chapters. After inserting the `\adjustmtc` command after `\tableofcontents`, I get chapter 1's minitoc showing up at chapter 2. Messing around further by inserting `\adjustmtc` in other places brings forward chapter 2's minitoc to chapter 1 and similar things.

I have also tried `\dominitoc` right after `\begin{document}`, but that seems to be irrelevant.

The `\adjustmtc` command also has an argument [...] into which I typed 3 for chapter 1 and 4 for chapter 2, which produces the right minitoc for chapter 1 but no minitoc for chapter 2.

Tried inserting `\listoffigures` too as I will have one eventually, but didn't change much. So, I will continue to mess around with this and see what happens. This is a start I think.

---

Edit: got it right so far, by adding one `\adjustmtc[2]` directly after `\tableofcontents` and now the right minitoc is showing up at the right chapter. I think one can just keep adjusting the value in the argument. It must be the unnumbered chapters before chapter 1 that has something to do with it I guess. These obviously have no sections, hence produce a blank minitoc, which is then appearing as "nothing" at chapters that do have sections. At least it seems that way.

Comment: Learned two more things - `\listoffigures`, `\listoftables` and using `\chapter*{}` does not seem to add to the chapter "count", and it seems you have to put `\adjustmtc[<x>]` right before the first minitoc-containing chapter.